# How to read all the heading tag on page and select one hading tag with a specific heading?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to read all the heading tag on a page and need to click only one heading tag named "dropdown". The sample structure of HTML is as follows

```
<div> <ul> <li>
<a href="submit_button_clicked.php">
<h2>Submit Button Clicked</h2>
<figure>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="dropdown.php">
<h2>Dropdown</h2>
<figure>
```

What i did is to create a custom xpath and store it in List,then iterate through list using for loop but i am unable to /read/write the value of tag  on console.

```
List l = ff.findElements(By.xpath("//div/ul/li/a/h2"));
```

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the text value of an element use:

```
element.getText();
```

In your case with your list it would look something like this:

```
for(WebElement element : l) {
    System.out.println(element.getText());
}
```

Since you want to click on an element, it would be better to use an xpath such as the following:

```
ff.findElements(By.xpath("h2[text()='Dropdown']")).click();
```

To find and click the specific element you want. The above xpath selector looks for a h2 element with the exact text 'Dropdown' and then clicks on it.

Comment: When i directly use the above code By.xpath("h2[text()='Dropdown']")).click();
I get an exception "Webdriver Element not Clickable"

Comment: Your element is not clickable at the time you're trying to click for some reason. Perhaps the dropdown is a disabled element, or the element has a height/width that is zero, or perhaps the element is invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Reading all `<h2>` tags can look something like:

```
List<WebElement> elements = ff.findElements(By.xpath("//h2"));
for(WebElement element : elements) {
    System.out.println(element.getText()); // just to show that it prints text
}
```

Note that I defined list as `List<WebElement>` which is to avoid usage of [raw types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html), and changed xpath to match any `<h2>`.

But when you need to click, usually you are required to click on parent `<a>` element, not on `<h2>` itself, i.e. the following should click on a correct link

```
ff.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='dropdown.php']")).click();
```

But if you want to find a link from header, in the above loop:

```
List<WebElement> elements = ff.findElements(By.xpath("//h2"));
for(WebElement element : elements) {
    if("Download".equals(element.getText()) {
        // get the parent <a> element and click on it
        element.findElement(By.xpath("..")).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: While iterating through elements , i got stale Element exception and hence cannot print all the value.any solution would be welcome :)

Comment: Did you see this: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp
Bottom line is: either you are getting those elements too early, when the page is still changing/loading; or page is changing all the time. So you have a few options: 1 - wait longer before getting elements; 2 - catch exception and continue with other elements on the list; 3 - retry from the beginning. What's the final goal of getting all `<h2>` elements?

Comment: Final Goal : Just to make script more dynamic. Clicking on just one heading from all the similar headings.

Comment: But why are you looping over all headers? You could just get the one you want directly by providing enough information in the xpath, get its parent link and click on it, like so: `WebElement dropdown = ff.findElement(By.xpath("//h2[text()='Dropdown']")); dropdown.findElement(By.xpath("..")).click(); }` and that's it.

Comment: Providing enough information in xpath and without iterating over all the heading tags. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please do it like below

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.seleniumhq.org");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
// Hi please do it like below ,take all H2 tag inside the list

List<WebElement> myH2Tags = driver.findElements(By.tagName("h2"));  // you can put any tag name as per your requirement

for(int i=0;i<myH2Tags.size();i++){
    System.out.println("Value of My H2 Tags are : " + myH2Tags.get(i).getText());
    if(myH2Tags.get(i).getText().equals("Selenium News")){ // you can replace this with drop down value
    myH2Tags.get(i).click();
        }
// to avoid stale element exception you have to re identify the elements
            myH2Tags = driver.findElements(By.tagName("h2"));
        }
```