# Is it possible to use Ajax/Jquery/jascript to build a drop down menu that jumps to a certain part of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've been searching for this here, but I can't seen to find anything related.

Let's say I have a list that starts with `<h2>` tags:

```
<h2>LIST ITEM 1</h2>

LIST CONTENT
______________________
<h2>LIST ITEM 2</h2>

LIST CONTENT
______________________

<h2>LIST ITEM 3</h2>

LIST CONTENT
______________________
```

But at the top of this list, I have a drop down menu:

```
>> CHOSE ITEM <<
```

Now comes my doubt, is it possible to retrieve all the `h2` from the list and put them as the drop down menu select list, just so whenever a person chooses an item, he will jump to the item he wants to see, and that with Ajax/Javascript/Jquery?

DEMO:

```
>> CHOSE ITEM <<
 _ LIST ITEM 1
 _ LIST ITEM 2
 _ LIST ITEM 3 <--- User clicks here



<h2>LIST ITEM 1</h2>

LIST CONTENT
______________________
<h2>LIST ITEM 2</h2>

LIST CONTENT
______________________

<h2>LIST ITEM 3</h2> <--- Then jumps to here

LIST CONTENT
______________________
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Is this list item1 -H2 in the page and on selection of dropdown menu you want to move the user to that section?

Comment: Cant you create dropdown while creating list items?

Comment: @VijendraKulhade There will be a list with, example, 50 items, each item has a h2, it's an article. The script should be able to identify all the h2 tags, put them inside the drop menu, so when an user selects an item from the menu, he automatically jumps to the article item.

Comment: @Rishi Sorry, I can't. That's why I'm asking. =/

Comment: I guess it's something like this, just found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37529062/how-to-read-all-the-heading-tag-on-page-and-select-one-hading-tag-with-a-specifi

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
var $headlines = $('h2');
var $dropdown = $('<select>');

$dropdown
    .insertBefore($headlines.first())
    .append('<option>Choose item</option>')
    .on('change', function () {
        var $option = $(this).find('option:selected');
        var $el = $option.data('headline');
        if (!$el) return;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $el.offset().top
       });
  });

$headlines
    .each(function () {
        var $el = $(this);
        $('<option>')
            .data('headline', $el)
            .text($el.text())
            .appendTo($dropdown);
    });
```